# d3 checking for types and setting a type accordingly

Tags: d3.js

I am working with a scatterplot in d3 and dots on the graph represent different papers. Papers on the graph can have different types ie. In_library, cites, cited_by-  and each type is given a different color. On click of a paper with type In_library papers that the clicked paper cites and papers that cites the clicked paper are retrieved from the database and displayed on the graph as different colours depending on its type.

The issue I am having is that for example, there are initially 4 papers on display on the graph and they are all of type In_library. When I click on one of these, papers linked to it will appear. But what I want is if a paper cites or is cited by a paper that is ALREADY of type In_library (is already on the graph), I want to recognise it as In_library and change the type to lets say
type "combo", instead of changing it to type "cites" or "cited by", so that visually I still know that it is in the library but it is also a paper linked to the selected paper. This is the relevent code I have so far to check if the retrieved paper is of type "In_library" and if so, change the type to "combo", else give it the type "cites" or "cited by" (depending on which connection it is in).

```
function clickHandler (d, i) {

d3.json("connection2.php?paperID="+d.ID, function(error, dataJson) {

                dataJson.forEach(function(d) {

                    d.YEAR = +d.YEAR;
                    d.counter = +d.counter;
                    if (d.type === "In_library") {

                        d.type = "combo";
                        }
                    else d.type = "cited by";


                allData.push(d);
    }
})          
}
```

Any help is appreciated I am new to d3, but also if what I am trying to do isnt feasible but if theres another way of achieving this I would appreciate that also. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the exact part you're struggling with? Does the code sample you provided act as you suspect it to? Where are you stuck now?

Comment: @MatthijsBrouns No its not acting like I would suspect it too :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are trying too hard here and not leveraging `d3` capabilities.  You have a bunch of uniquely identified circles; when you draw your plot, you want those that are new to the plot to be a certain color.  When updating, you want those that were already there to be a new color.  This sounds tailor made for the the [enter/update/exit pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234).

```
 function update(data){

    // this is our overall update selection
    var sel = svg.selectAll('circle')
      .data(data, function(d,i){
        return d.id;
      });

    // those that are updated
    // mark with combo class
    sel.attr("class", "combo");

    // these are the newly arriving guys
    sel.enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr('cx', function(d){
        return s(d.x);
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d){
        return s(d.y);
      })
      .attr('r', 25)
      .attr("class", "in_library");
  }
```

Here's a [quick example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rekM9lM7CamACPrzs8UX?p=preview).